# what size should I use to put a background image on the navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm looking on the internet and I'm told that the sizes should be 320x44 and 640 x 88, but I tried these and I have the following result:

[image]

The duplicate image to fill the entire space of the navigation bar, which are the correct sizes and as an achievement also that does not cover the state bar. Thank in objective C

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to add color overlay customize navigation controller and add subview with autolayout. It worked for me to place a logo in one of my project.

Answer (score 0):

Your image has the wrong mode.

When you are setting your image, use the following to create the bars image for the appropriate fill / layout mode:

```
UIImage *barImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"]
                     resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
                     resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
```

Now you can go about setting your navigation bars background image with either `UIBarMetricsDefault` or `UIBarMetricsDefault`

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:barImage forBarMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)];
```

**OR** if you are just setting this within your view controller with a parent navigation controller:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:barImage forBarMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)];
```

This will set your image as the background image with the correct resizing to ensure it fills the *entire* navigation bar. Happy coding!